# Which entries on two different Excel files are similar or different

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

So I've got three columns of data on each excel file. In my example, the first is a type of fruit, the second color, third amount. I want to find out which entries that match exactly (Fruit, color & amount) are matched between both files and also which entries are totally unique to each file. Normally I'd use Vlookup for this sort of thing but sadly there is a lot of duplicates in each column. I also think Concatenate could potentially be an avenue but I feel their are much easier ways of doing this. Pretend rows G, H & I are on the different excel file

[image]

Comment: COUNTIFS could work.

Comment: Interesting, I could potentially see away with COUNTIFS but it seems a little overcomplex. I could combine the two lists and then use COUNTIFS to see which entries have 2 examples and also which has 1 but that doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: With your current example: `=COUNTIFS(G:G,A1,H:H,B1,I:I,C1)` and drag down. Similarly, `=COUNTIFS(A:A,G1,B:B,H1,C:C,I1)`.

Comment: With an IF: `=IF(COUNTIFS(G:G,A1,H:H,B1,I:I,C1),"Exists","Unique")`

Comment: This appears to be the most correct answer! Unfortunately, it turns out based on my data set there are incredibly small differences in the entries that I didn't realize were present. For example "LLC" vs "L.L.C". I've tried many manipulations but for the size of the data set it appears the best course of action is manual comparisons. Correct answer though!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check from GHI -> ABC as well it is just the same code again...
=IF(XLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2,G:G&H:H&I:I;I:I,"",0,1)=C2,"Match","Unique")

[image]

Comment: While small, there's the chance for false positives if you concatenate here, because `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` concatenated would match `foo`, `ba`, and `rbaz` for example. The `COUNTIFS` approach does not have this issue.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, you are absolutely right. I believed the chance of that, in this case, was infinitesimal. I had not considered using Contifs in this manner. Good post, thanks!